# Запятая или точка с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, точка-с-запятой

Скажите, пожалуйста, на месте () следует ставить запятую или точку с запятой? "Выходные дни мы с друзьями проведём на природе() Миша возьмёт палатку, мангал, спальные мешки".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбор знака препинания не очень удобно делать, просто в свободном порядке перечисляя знаки, стили и смысловые оттенки. Такие задачи удобно решать по схеме "смысл - форма (грамматическая и интонационная) - знак препинания".

СМЫСЛ (два варианта)

(1) Это простое повествование, связь событий не подчеркивается.

(2) Автор хочет обозначить взаимосвязь сообщений. Для определения вида связи попробуем преобразовать БСП в СПП: "Выходные дни мы с друзьями проведем на природе, в связи с чем Миша возьмет палатку, мангал, спальные мешки". Это придаточное присоединительного характера (значение причина-следствие, скорее, на втором плане).

ВЫБИРАЕМ ФОРМУ и ЗНАК ПРЕПИНАНИЯ

Грамматическая форма уже выбрана (это БСП), поэтому оттенки смысла обозначаем с помощью интонации.

РЕШЕНИЕ

(1)  "Выходные дни мы с друзьями проведем на природе,Миша возьмет палатку, мангал, спальные мешки". Перечислительная интонация соответствует запятой. (Точка с запятой не походит, так как  ставится при разной тематике сообщений).

(2) "Выходные дни мы с друзьями проведем на природе - Миша возьмет палатку, мангал, спальные мешки". Присоединительная интонация соответствует тире.  (Присоединительная интонация - это небольшая пауза, а далее второе сообщение).

Comment: София, спасибо Вам большое за такой развернутый и понятный ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Здесь вообще-то нужно поставить точку, так как предложения не связаны друг с другом до степени точки с запятой. Но точка с запятой в таком нераспространенном и разговорном по смыслу предложении неуместна. Тире возможно с большой натяжкой. А вот обычная запятая на крайний случай сгодится. Думаю, у этого текста есть продолжение - о том, кто что возьмет или сделает. И это простое перечисление подготовительных мероприятий.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нужно поставить тире, так как это бессоюзное сложное предложение, вторая часть которого показывает следствие того, о чем говорится в первой части. В бессоюзных предложениях правила постановки знаков определяются именно смыслом частей предложения. Если бы было не "возьмет палатку, мангал", а, например, "возьмет мольберт и кисти", то эта часть являлась бы следствием с большой натяжкой. Это было бы просто продолжением повествования. Кто чем будет заниматься на природе. В этом случае точка с запятой была бы уместна.

Comment: Т.е. тире ставится по смыслу, а не по правилу? Ведь если бы было не "возьмет палатку, мангал", а например "возьмет мольберт и кисти". То эта честь не являлась бы следствием. Это было бы, на мой взгляд (возможно я ошибаюсь), просто продолжением повествования. Кто чем будет заниматься на природе.

Comment: Смысл  не  противопоставляется  правилу,  т.к.  правила  применения  знаков  препинания  оформляют  смысловые  оттенки.